# How to implement AsyncTask connecting to a server and parsing JSON

Tags: java, android, json, android-asynctask

my app does connect to a local server on my pc (xampp) and I would like to implement asynctask in order to avoid app crash or block when the server is not online or there are any other problems. Reading on the web I found that the best solution should be asynctask but I really can't understand very well how to implement it.
I have a JSONParser class that connect to the server, then another userfunctions class with multiple functions that call JSONParser class...should I implement asynctask on JSONParser class or on the other one?
This is my JSONParser class :

```
public class JSONParser{

static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";

// constructor
public JSONParser() {

}   

public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url, List<NameValuePair> params) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {
        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "n");
        }

        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
        Log.e("JSON", json);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);            
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;

}
```

How should my class become with asynctask and overriding doinbackground method?
Then how should I call it in order to execute the getjsonfromurl method?
For example when now I need to parse a JSON I simply write

```
jsonParser = new JSONParser();
JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(URL, params);
```

Can you also explain when it's better to use asynctask and when multithreading?

Edit: I add my UserFunctions class so that you can provide a real example on my code, because I still don't know how to handle all..

```
public class UserFunctions{

private JSONParser jsonParser;

// Testing in localhost using xampp 
// use http://10.0.2.2/ to connect to your localhost ie http://localhost/
private static String URL = "http://192.168.1.102/android_login_api/"; //"http://192.168.1.102/android_login_api/"

private static String login_tag = "login";
private static String register_tag = "register";
private static String new_reservation_tag = "reservation";
private static String get_reservation_tag = "get_reservation";

// constructor
public UserFunctions(){
    jsonParser = new JSONParser();
}

/**
 * function make Login Request
 * @param email
 * @param password
 * */
public JSONObject loginUser(String email, String password){
    // Building Parameters
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", login_tag));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
    JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(URL, params);
    //Log.e("JSON", json.toString());
    return json;
}

/**
 * function make Registration Request
 * @param name
 * @param email
 * @param password
 * */
public JSONObject registerUser(String name, String email, String password){
    // Building Parameters
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", register_tag));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));

    // getting JSON Object
    JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(URL, params);
    // return json
    return json;
}

/**
 * function make new Reservation
 * @param email
 * @param attivita
 * @param data
 * @param ora
 * */
public JSONObject newReservation(String email, String attivita, String data, String ora){
    // Building Parameters
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    //String data_string = data.toString();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", new_reservation_tag));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("attivita", attivita));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("data", data));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ora", ora));
    JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(URL, params);
    //Log.e("JSON", json.toString());
    return json;
}

/**
 * function get Reservation
 * @param email
 * */
public JSONObject getReservation(String email){
    // Building Parameters
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    //String data_string = data.toString();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", get_reservation_tag));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
    JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(URL, params);
    //Log.e("JSON", json.toString());
    return json;
}

/**
 * function get Reservation number
 * @param email
 * */
public int getReservationNum(String email){
    JSONObject json = getReservation(email);
    JSONArray jsona = null;
    int rn = 0;
        try {
            jsona = json.getJSONArray("reservation");
            if(jsona.length() > 0){
                rn = jsona.length();
                return rn;
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    return rn;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) is, in fact, multithreading..

It allows you to pass a task for background processing without blocking your ui thread.

Furthermore, it also allows you to easily update your ui where needed (in Android ui can only be accessed by the ui thread).

Leaving some complexities aside, AsyncTask usage can look like this:

```
new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
    @Override 
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) { 
        // perform your background processing here; it will run on a worker thread
         jsonParser = new JSONParser();
         JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(URL, params);
         parseYourJson();
         return null; 
    } 

    @Override 
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // update you ui after background processing is completed
    }
}.execute();
```

Note that doInBackground() must not propagate exceptions. This will result in your program crashing.

As for the Json parsing, you can do it as part of the doInBackground() i.e. in the background. 
Consider using [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) for the task. I've used it for years with zero complains.

Comment: Can you please provide a concrete example on my code?
You already have my JSONParser class, while my userfunctions class as said before just build the params and pass url and params to jsonparser object like this:
....
JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(URL, params);
        return json;

How and where should I implement the asynctask?
And how do I get the value returned by doinbackground?
Thanks

Comment: I edited my first question too, if you can provide me an example on my code you would be very kind.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you do have time to learn a new approach, maybe you could read the official training lessons about Volley, a Google library made to ease your web requests, specially when requestion a JSON response or downloading images. You can find it here: http://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html